# Unit Testing Bootstrap Modal Redirect

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, redirect

I've been unable resolve this issue on IRC, hoping I could find some guidance here. I have the following test:

```
def test_validation_errors_return_hops_list_page(self):
    response = self.client.post(
        '/beerdb/add/hops',
        data={
            'name': '',
            'min_alpha_acid': '',
            'max_alpha_acid': '',
            'country': '',
            'comments': ''
        }, follow=True
    )

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'homebrewdatabase/addhops.html')
    name_validation_error = escape("A hop name is required")
    min_alpha_acid_error = escape("You must enter a min alpha acid")
    max_alpha_acid_error = escape("You must enter a max alpha acid")
    country_error = escape("You must enter a country")
    comments_error = escape("You must enter a comment")

    self.assertContains(response, name_validation_error)
    self.assertContains(response, min_alpha_acid_error)
    self.assertContains(response, max_alpha_acid_error)
    self.assertContains(response,country_error)
    self.assertContains(response, comments_error)
```

It's failing on `self.assertContains(response, name_validation_error)`. Here's the trace back:

```
Failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/USER/workspace/PycharmProjects/hashtagbrews/homebrewdatabase/tests/test_views.py", line 189, in test_validation_errors_return_hops_list_page
self.assertContains(response, name_validation_error)
File "/Users/USER/workspace/Envs/hashtagbrews/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 398, in assertContains
msg_prefix + "Couldn't find %s in response" % text_repr)
AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find 'A hop name is required' in response
```

My view in views.py renders the `hops.html` template with errors when the form is invalid:

```
def addhops(request):

    add_form = HopForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if add_form.is_valid():
            Hop.objects.create(name=request.POST['name'],
                           min_alpha_acid=request.POST['min_alpha_acid'],
                           max_alpha_acid=request.POST['max_alpha_acid'],
                           country=request.POST['country'],
                           comments=request.POST['comments']
                           )
        return redirect('hops_list')
    else:
        hops_list = Hop.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'homebrewdatabase/hops.html', {'hops': hops_list, 'form': add_form})
return render(request, 'homebrewdatabase/addhops.html', {'form': add_form})
```

When I manually click through the site, I get exactly what I'm looking for: a redirect from the modal to the main hops page list with a Bootstrap alert box at the top containing an unordered list of errors from add_hops.errors. I've printed out the response after the post request (`self.client.post('url', data={invalid data})`) and it only contains the modal form. What would be the proper method to finish this test? Or do I need to rewrite my form validation?

Comment: clear your terminal, add `print response`  after `response = ...` then run just that test. Then check what you are asserting is actually in the printed output - cause you are failing on your first assertion, anything could be happening e.g. page not rendering etc.

Comment: also good idea to reverse urls instead of `/beerdb/add/hops'

Comment: The issue is, as I suspected, response.context['request']. It reads as follows 'request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/beerdb/add/hops/'. So it's running an additional GET request in the '/beerdb/add/hops' url which is returning the modal. I need a way to get it to check the template rendered when the form is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here, as identified in the comments, is that the Django test client runs a GET request on the `addhops` view method after executing the post request. According to the view logic, if the method isn't POST, then it returns the bootstrap modal, which does not contain the form errors by design. So the test will fail when using the test client. However, the test can be altered to, instead, use the `HttpRequest` object to send invalid data in a POST request and then assert that the content contains the form errors. So I rewrote the test to use the following, which passes--

```
def test_validation_errors_return_hops_list_page(self):
    request = HttpRequest()

    request.method = 'POST'
    request.POST['name'] = ''
    request.POST['min_alpha_acid'] = ''
    request.POST['max_alpha_acid'] = ''
    request.POST['country'] = 'USA'
    request.POST['comments'] = ''

    response = addhops(request)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    name_validation_error = escape("A hop name is required")
    min_alpha_acid_error = escape("You must enter a min alpha acid")
    max_alpha_acid_error = escape("You must enter a max alpha acid")
    comments_error = escape("You must enter a comment")

    self.assertContains(response, name_validation_error)
    self.assertContains(response, min_alpha_acid_error)
    self.assertContains(response, max_alpha_acid_error)
    self.assertContains(response, comments_error)
```

I cannot assert which template was used as `assertTemplateUsed` is a method that belongs to the test client, but my functional tests with selenium should be enough to check that the required elements are in the rendered view. This may have to be changed in the future, but for now, it's enough to work with.

Comment: glad you got that sorted. Instead of assertTemplateUsed you could check that your #form-id is in the response.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I need to check my response.content again to see if the modal's actually coming in. I didn't store the modal content in the same template, but rather put the modal calls in the main page and then divided the modal's into their own template. I'll probably end up merging the add/edit and delete views at some point.